# Why must I create a type alias when using a variadic constructor function?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, variadic-templates, c++14

I have a templated base class that takes an N amount of types:

```
template <typename... Ts>
class Base{};
```

When using protected inheritance on that base class,

```
template <typename... Ts>
class Derived : protected Base<Ts...>{
   //like so...
};
```

I would like to additionally include the public constructors of the base class:

```
template <typename... Ts>
class Derived : protected Base<Ts...>{

   //create an alias
   using Parent = Base<Ts...>;

   //get all constructors as well
   using Parent::Parent; 
};
```

This works.
However, why must I include the `Parent` alias?

Is doesn't seem as though I can get the constructors without it.  The following attempt does not work:

```
template <typename... Ts>
class Derived : protected Base<Ts...>{

   //get all constructors as well
   using Base<Ts...>::Base<Ts...>; 
};
```

**error:**

```
clang++ -std=c++1z -o main v.cpp
error: expected ';' after using declaration
       using Base<Ts...>::Base<Ts...>; 
                              ^
                              ;
1 error generated.
```

I can cut off the template part, and it compiles, but this does not appear to be correct:

```
template <typename... Ts>
class Derived : protected Base<Ts...>{

   //get all constructors as well
   using Base<Ts...>::Base; 
};
```

The reason I don't think it is correct is because it does not appear to work on vector.
**does not compile:**

```
template <typename... Ts>
class Derived : protected std::vector<Ts...>{

   //get all constructors as well
   using std::vector<Ts...>::std::vector; 
};
```

However, using an alias does work.
**compiles:**

```
template <typename... Ts>
class Derived : protected std::vector<Ts...>{

   //create an alias
   using Parent = std::vector<Ts...>;

   //get all constructors as well
   using Parent::Parent; 
};
```

**Question:**
Do I have to use an alias to get the same functionally, or is there a way to inline this without creating a new name for the base type?

Comment: `std::vector<Ts...>::std::vector` shouldn't work in that using statement.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Right, it does not work for vector.  And although it may compile for other types, I suspect it is not the same as using Alias::Alias.

Comment: No, I mean it should be `namespace::type::type` not `namespace::type::namespace::type`

Comment: Oh, I see.  Yeah, excluding the namespace now gives me the same error as before( the example without the vector where clang is expecting a colon sooner than it gets one).  At least the compiler errors are consistent now.

Comment: the constructor is **not** `Base<Ts...>` because the constructor is not templated. `using Base<Ts...>::Base;` is the correct way to write it.

Comment: `using vector<Ts...>::vector` is what you are looking for. Your alias just fixes your syntax errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example `Base` does not have a template constructor so `using Base<Ts...>::Base<Ts...>;` is trying to find a constructor that does not exist.

Imagine I had a class *like* yours

```
class Base{
    public:
        Base(){}

        template<typename ... Ts>
        Base(){}
};
```

Which constructor would `using Base<Ts...>::Base<Ts...>` choose?

The reason that `using Parent = Base<Ts...>` works is because when you write `using Parent::Parent` you are trying to find a constructor of `Parent` that is *not* templated. It expands to `using Base<Ts...>::Base;`.

Comment: while this answer looks correct, it is not. The reason is that the name of the base class's constructor is not `Base<Ts...>`. It is `Base`. See my answer.

Comment: the reason that the alias Parent::Parent works is because  in the case of A::B, A is a *type* and B is a *name*. so Parent::Parent means use the *name* Parent from the *type* Parent.

Comment: *"using Base<Ts...>::Base<Ts...>; is trying to find a constructor that does not exist"* This is either incorrect or misleading: Even if you add a constructor template and try to introduce this via a using-declaration, the compiler will report an error: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb192e1f99fdd3c7 I *think* `Base<Ts...>::Base<Ts...>` is not a legal qualified-id since `Base` is dependent.

Comment: *shrug* It is simply forbidden explicitly in [namespace.udecl]p5: *"A _using-declaration_ shall not name a _template-id_."*

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a type alias. The problem is that the constuctor of `Base<Ts...>` is not called `Base<Ts...>`. It's called `Base`.

This works:

```
template<class...Ts>
struct Base {

};

template<class...Ts>
struct Derived : Base<Ts...>
{
    using Base<Ts...>::Base;
};
```

In addition, the name of `std::vector<...>`'s constructor is not `std::vector`, it is `vector`

This also works:

```
template<class...Ts>
struct Derived : std::vector<Ts...>
{
    using std::vector<Ts...>::vector;
};
```

However, *don't derive from std:: containers!* Encapsulate them.

Comment: This is exactly what my answer says. I even gave an example where the different names matter.

Comment: The relation between *constructors* and *names* is a bit weird - I have to admit I don't fully understand it. One passage in the Standard says that *constructors do not have names*, but another says that *constructors can be found in name lookup*. -- In relation to the OP's issue, `Base<Ts...>` can be used to declare the constructor: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fdbf380a0ca21f0a (although that is not accepted when defining it out-of-line http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc9cc0347a8f24c2 )

Comment: Maybe you're right: `Base<Ts...>` *does not name a constructor*, and there's a special exception for declaring a constructor within the class body that allows using a *class-name* (which can be a *simple-template-id*).

Answer (score 1):

`using Base<Ts...>::Base<Ts...>;` is illegal because of a very general rule in [namespace.udecl]p5:

> A *using-declaration* shall not name a *template-id*.

This is very similar to the fact that you cannot name a specific overload in using-declarations. However, I do not know the rationale for this rule.

---

The relation between constructors and names... is complicated:

- "Constructors do not have names." <sup>[class.ctor]p1</sup>
- "The point of declaration of a *using-declaration* that does not name a constructor [...]" <sup>[class.ctor]p4</sup>

So while constructors do not *have names*, they can *be named*. To me, this seems similar to anonymous types:

```
struct { int m; } x;
decltype(x) // refers to the type of `x` which has no name
```

A *using-declaration* that shall inherit constructors must *name a constructor*.

---

[class.qual]p2 specifies how a constructor can be named in qualified-ids (consisting of a *nested-name-specifier* and an *unqualified-id*):

> In a lookup in which function names are not ignored and the
>   *nested-name-specifier* nominates a class `C`:
>
> - (2.1) if the name specified after the *nested-name-specifier*, when looked up in `C`, is the *injected-class-name* of `C`, or
> - (2.2) in a *using-declaration* that is a *member-declaration*, if the name specified after the *nested-name-specifier* is the same as
>     the *identifier* or the *simple-template-id*’s *template-name* in the last
>     component of the *nested-name-specifier*,
>
> the name is instead considered to name the constructor of class `C`.

To address/comment some other answers, I'll digress a bit..

One can argue that (2.1) does not apply in the OP: while `Base` contains an *injected-class-name*, this name is `Base` and not `Base<Ts...>`. The name specified after the *nested-name-specifier* is `Base<Ts...>`, which is not the *injected-class-name*.

Note that the *injected-class-name* of a dependent base class is not known until instantiation time. Consider

```
template<typename T>
struct foo : T {
    using T::name;
    void name(double);
};

struct name { name(int); };
struct bar { void name(int); };

foo<name> // constructor inheritance?
foo<bar>  // makes a function visible?
```

clang++ rejects this example, while g++ accepts it. This is [CWG 2070](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#2070)

We do know however at the point of definition that `Base` in the OP is a class, and therefore could *infer* the *injected-class-name*. This would require a distinction between types whose name is know at the point of definition and those where it is not. Alias templates can hide this, so this is not a trivial distinction of the *form* of the qualified-id in the using-declaration.

In any case, the bullet point (2.2) does not apply to `Base<Ts...>::Base<Ts...>`: Its *nested-name-specifier* is `Base<Ts...>`. The *template-name* of this is `Base`. The name after the *nested-name-specifier* is `Base<Ts...>`.

---

[class.qual]p2.2 allows using `Base<Ts...>::Base` and `parent::parent`, simply *by looking at the identifiers used within the qualified-id*. No actual name lookup needs to be performed here. The form itself is sufficient to name a constructor.